# Is there a standard for storing and displaying Pratt certificates of primality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a standard using XML tags or something else for storing a Pratt certificate of primality?

What is the standard for the display?

I am aware that one would need the prime $p$, a primitive root $a$ and the factorization of $p-1$ along with a certificate for each prime in the factorization of $p-1$.  I just don't know how this is expected to be stored or displayed.

Comment: It is more a matter of how a mathematician would communicate a prime discovery to another mathematician for verification.  This would have to be done electronically to avoid errors.  I was wondering how this was done.  I prefer using a standard format to avoid confusion.

Comment: Typically http://factordb.com is used.  It accepts Primo certificates.  The verifier also supports MPU certificates but the web site has a pre-test that only takes Primo.  It also takes N-1, N+1, and hybrid N-1 / N+1 proofs by storing a helper file of factors, and possibly a base.  I believe this is done so PFGW can be used (PFGW does not output a certificate or any intermediate info however).  I wish it would use a more formal certificate for these methods.

Comment: This would be another reason to have a standard for the certificates.  Then there would be no ambiguity when entering results into such databases. The factordb site looks interesting.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'd need to construct the format and get people to use it.  There would be a bunch of constructive and destructive criticism, as well as endless bikeshedding.  You'd probably want a verifier that reads it or there wouldn't be much point for anyone to adopt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no standard in use.  Every program uses their own method, with varying levels of documentation.

I came up with my own format, described [here](https://github.com/danaj/Math-Prime-Util-GMP/blob/master/xt/proof-text-format.txt), along with a verifier (used by factordb) and proof software that generates these forms.  The documentation could be improved.  It covers ECPP (with simple n-1 and n+1) as well as BLS75 (T3, T5, T15) and Lucas.

My code doesn't generate strict Pratt certificates (e.g. using type Lucas) because BLS75 theorem 5 is much more efficient, not to mention ECPP.  But the certificate allows them and the verifiers handle it.

A small example using the Lucas type (as used for a Pratt certificate) would look like:

```
[MPU - Primality Certificate]
Version 1.0

Proof for:
N 8087094497428743437627091507362881

Type Lucas
N  8087094497428743437627091507362881
Q[1]  6360775529
Q[2]  1237110551
Q[3]  98277749
Q[4]  3631
Q[5]  5
Q[6]  3
Q[7]  2
A     13
```

Any Q[i] larger than $2^{64}$ would need its own entry as well (which for a Pratt certificate would also be of type Lucas, but the verifiers will accept any type).  Without that, the certificate will not verify.  I chose $2^{64}$ since we can run BPSW on anything smaller and have a verified result.  Primo chose $34 * 10^{13}$ as its cutoff (the BPSW result was not known when Primo chose its format).  [Update: Just two days ago he released a new "format 4" certificate that uses the BPSW result]

---

Addendum for certificates:

- [Primo](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html), the gold standard of free primality provers, defined its own format for ECPP certificates.  It is well defined, will verify its own certificates, and there are two independent open source tools that also verify them.
- [Perl/ntheory](https://metacpan.org/pod/ntheory) is what I describe above (MPU certificates).  I believe it is well defined, it has proof software in Perl and C+GMP, and verifiers in Perl and C+GMP.  ECPP as well as BLS75-T5 and some other methods.
- [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Arithmetic_functions.html#isprime) will produce a $p-1$ certificate with `isprime(p,1)`.  It looks like BLS75 theorem 5 using the BPSW ($2^{64}$) cutoff (technically it's C&P's theorem 4.1.5 based on BLS75-T5).  Its documentation is very brief but basically is a matrix with rows of "Q A x" where x is either 1 (Q < 2^{64}) or another matrix.  Factorization only is done to $p^{1/3}$ which is what BLS75-T5 needs.
- [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/tutorial/PrimalityProving.html)'s `PrimeQCertificate[n]` will produce certificates.  It doesn't seem to have any documentation on how to parse them.  It will verify its own certificates.  For small inputs it generates Pratt certificates, while larger inputs use a "Atkin-Goldwasser-Kilian-Morain" certificate.
- Morain's very old ecpp program will output ECPP certificates.  I have not attempted to decipher them.
- I wrote a Perl program to turn the output of GMP-ECPP into MPU certificates, which can then run through its verifier.  GMP-ECPP is significantly slower than ecpp-dj or Primo however.
- I also wrote a Perl program that converts ECPP certificates produced by SAGE's ecpp function (which AFAIK never got merged into master) to MPU certificates, which can then run through its verifier.  It's a neat small implementation that's good for not-very-large inputs.
- [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numlib-proveprime.html), related to MATLAB, seems to generate ECPP certificates.  I haven't looked closely since I don't have their software, but it looks like converting to MPU certificates would be straightforward.

Comment: It makes sense not to add a separate certificate for small primes.  I liked the way your certificate in the link gave verification steps in the comments in case the verifier personally opened the file.  I assume if you were communicating your results electronically you would assume the verifier's computer could parse the certificate.  That is why I was thinking XML or some other tagging mechanism would have been used, but what you have here seems easy to parse.

Comment: I was influenced somewhat by Marcel Martin's Primo certificates, which have this simple per-line variable space value format.  It's easy to parse in C or Perl without having to pull in XML/YAML/JSON parsing.  I admit XML could have some advantages.  One difference with MPU certs is that they are a hash rather than a tree (it gives more freedom in operation order in the prover).  A certificate description IMO needs to have enough info for a third party to write their own verifier.  Again Marcel Martin did this excellently.

Comment: Marcel Martin's certificates also include who found the prime and when and on what computer.  That is all valuable information although not required to verify the certificate.  The reason I prefer some type of markup language is that it gets this standardized like LaTeX does for text.  It also can be stored in a database better although they may both be stored as blobs.

Comment: Are you sure?  The certificate documentation doesn't include that information, nor does Primo add it to the certificates.  There is a theoretically unique ID, a created date, a file name, run times, comments, and a signature.  The certificates it generates, and most of those found on factordb, do not include who or any info about the computer used.  I don't see anything like that in the certificates from his page nor the ones from new or old Primo.  Of course we can add it to comments.

Comment: The one I looked at was on the top 20 page: http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/top20.html.  I downloaded and unzipped the one by Giovanni and Marco La Barbera at the bottom of the page.  The ecpp400.zip file unzipped to new400.out.  In the Comments sections was that information.

Comment: But it's not in Cami's 2015 certificate, for instance.  Tom Wu's 2014 one has the comment "Put here any comment..."  The MPU format allows comments almost anywhere using a "#" at the start of a line.  Either one makes automated parsing problematic.

Comment: It looks like this is information one has manually inserted after the certificate was created.  Although the comment information isn't useful for verifying, it is nice to know since it takes weeks for someone to find that prime if they are lucky to not select a composite number to check.  Also the software should be able to tell more precisely the hardware specifications of the computer and the operating system and also date when the certificate was created.  The certificate shouldn't have to be opened up and then modified by the user to add the comments.

Comment: BPSW is used at all steps of Primo and ecpp-dj (MPU), so composites get rejected almost immediately.  No luck involved, but sometimes weeks or months to complete the proof.  For Primo, the input is taken as a text file which can contain comments, which are copied to the cert, so technically we don't need to edit the cert.  Anyway, the point seems to be that ideally a cert should have extra additional metadata.  Hashing it out is probably best on a forum (e.g. mersenneforum) or as part of a research group.

Comment: It looks like W3C has an ISO standard MathML using conceptual tags, that is, the tags aren't just to display something.  There may be enough here to generate a type of certificate based on standards.  I plan to ask PrimeGrid what they use to store data.  Thanks.  You have got me past some conceptual problems related to this issue.  There may be no specific standard for certifications, by what standards do exist could be used to build one without it being totally arbitrary.